# How to create a pie menu in Unity 3D for switching weapons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

Long story short, I'm trying to create a UI panel where you hold and drag your mouse wheel button and select the option you want (while holding that button). So it is a pop-up menu that is triggered when you press the mouse wheel button. When you release the button, there are 2 possible situations:

1. You didn't move your cursor to a valid position. The pop-up menu is closed.
2. You moved your cursor to a valid position. You triggered an option from this pop-up menu.

To give you an example, the weapon switch system in, say, Tomb Raider does this similarly. It looks like a roulette, you hold the button then move your cursor to a certain location that "belongs" to, say, shotgun. Then you release the button, the menu is closed and now you are equiped with a shotgun.
Right now, the pop-up panel kinda works. However it's not a hold-release mechanism but a click mechanism. You click the button once, then the menu pops up and stays there.

How do you do that in Unity3D?

Here is my script so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class PosSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator  posSelectorAnimator;
    public GameObject posSelector;
    public Animator posButtonAnimator;

    void Start ()
    {
        posSelectorAnimator = posSelector.GetComponent<Animator>();
        
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse2))
        {
            Open();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse2))
        {
            Close();
        }
    }

    void Open()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Debug.Log("Middle button is pressed.");
        posSelector.transform.position = (mousePos);
        posSelectorAnimator.SetBool("ButtonDown", true);
    }

    void Close()
    {

        if (posButtonAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Highlighted"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Position selected.");
            Debug.Log(posButtonAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).shortNameHash);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Input not found.");
            Debug.Log(posButtonAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).shortNameHash);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you are cresting is called a pie menu.
You could create a script for the buttons inside your pie menu. Then let that script inherit from MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler and IPointerExitHandler.
These interfaces force you to implement the following methods:

```
 public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     PosSelector.selectedObject = gameObject;
 }

 public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     PosSelector.selectedObject = null;
 }
```

Now create a static field in your PosSelector script called selectedObject:

```
public static GameObject selectedObject;
```

Then in your Close() Method, you can use selectedObject as your output:

```
void Close()
{
    //Close your menu here using the animator

    //Return if nothing was selected
    if(selectedObject == null) 
        return;

    //Select a weapon or whatever you want to do with your output
}
```

Also, consider renaming your question to something like "how to create a pie menu in unity? " so that other people with the same question have an easier time finding this question

Comment: Thanks a lot! And the title of the post is edited. Just out of curiosity: Can you still do the hover-release mechanism without the pie menu?

Comment: Of course, "pie menu" is just the name of the menu design. It does not have anything to do with the implementation. You can use IPointerEnterHandler and IPointerExitHandlers event methods on any ui object